# Disable Npm warnings as Errors: build definition tfs

Tags: tfs, npm, build-definition

I am getting npm warnings as errors during build using build definition.
[image]

I then added following property in **MSBuild Arguments** in **Build Definition**:

```
/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=False
```

but it is not working yet.

I also cross-checked by right-clicking each project and none of them has the option "Treat Warnings as Errors" checked.

I am calling **npm install** command from post-build script.

I also restarted build controller and build agent after changes that I tried but no success.

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to use the `loglevel` option so that warnings simply don't appear at all. This avoids the problem of having warnings show in standard error thus halting builds or writing errors for warnings.

I typically use `npm install --loglevel=error --no-update-notifier`. I've noticed that update-checks also can interrupt the build process for npm.

Comment: @Codezila this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

MSBuild arguments won't help you here... the post-build script runs after MSBuild has finished executing.

The problem is that **npm** is writing its warnings to the `stderr` stream, which TFS detects and reports as a an error.  You can suppress this by redirecting the error stream to `stdout` like so:

```
npm install 2>&1
```

However, this will suppress errors as well as warnings, which may or may not be acceptable in your case.  In our case, we call **npm install** from a PowerShell script during the pre-build script.  We redirect the output, but then we also scan the output looking for the string `ERR!` like so:

```powershell
& npm install *>&1 | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = $_
    if ( $obj -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] ) {
        $s = $obj.Exception.Message
    }
    else {
        $s = $obj.ToString()
    }
    if ( $s.Contains('ERR!') ) {
        Write-Error $s
    }
    else {
        Write-Output $s
    }
}
$LASTEXITCODE = 0
```

Note that we also set `$LASTEXITCODE` to zero so that PowerShell doesn't pass the exit code from **npm** back to TFS.

Comment: Is this still working for you? I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: @MichaelArmstrong Since then, we have upgraded to TFS 2017 and are now using the new build agents, so I don't know.  The npm tasks there work great. If it is at all possible for you, I highly recommend doing the same.

Comment: Any suggestion when I have the problem on one agent but not on the other? Both VM's in Azure, the one with the problem is the latest windows 10 server VS2019 community edition template.

Answer (score 6):

Within the CI Server, This is a very common issue that pipeline gets failed whenever we run 'npm build'

We receive some warnings and the CI server considers them as errors and the pipeline gets terminated.

To remove this error just add environment variables within the pipeline as mentioned below:

```
env:
  CI: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the correct syntax instead of yours

```
/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="false"
```

Comment: It doesn't work with XAML build definition in TFS2015.3. Warning from NPM still get treated as errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can silence npm during the install process with the `--silent` argument:

```
npm install --silent
```

You don't need any msbuild argument this way.