# I can't publish the application via dotnet publish. On one it's fine, on the other it gives an error

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-core

I can't publish the application via dotnet publish. On one it's fine, on the other it gives an error

```
Failed to compile.

Warning
(3786:3) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

C:\\GitLab-Runner\\builds\\9hzz-ST3\\0\\root\\gitlab-ci-iis\\Project1\\Project1.csproj(36,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
```

The dotnet build runs fine.

Where else can I dig?

Required versions of NetCore are the same (3.1.25)

- 1 server (all ok)

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

- 2 server (with error)

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.419 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: Everything is working. But only when running through the command line. But it does not work through Gitlab ci. Never tried before through the command line, and it's a pity, I lost so much time ( Now I'm figuring it out

Comment: I found out that npm returns error code 1 because of warrnings
And that's why the pipelines were crashing, I had to fix it with crutches.
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917977/disable-npm-warnings-as-errors-build-definition-tfs)